# Different Problem of Change Image every second. Using same Image URL, no database

Tags: javascript, jquery

The image url contains an image having a file name of platecar.jpg, initially it will be displayed every second but if I replace the platecar.jpg image with another different image but has same name platecar.jpg, it doesn't change unless i do refresh with hard empty cache and hard reload on the browser.

I'm not yet home so i don't have laptop and i don't want to use database either for this. I was thinking of AJAX, would that do?

my current code in:

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    displayNewSnapshot();   
})

function displayNewSnapshot() {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        let imageDataURL = "/images/plate_car.jpg";
        $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', imageDataURL);
        console.log('img loaded.');
    }, 1000);   
}
```

html

```
<body>
<div>
    <img id="uploadedImage" src="">
</div>
</body>
```

The operation is like the platecar.jpg file will be overwritten every second or so and the page will have to display that image every second or so also but it does not happen unless empty cache and hard reload by refresh. I do not want it to have an auto-refresh code because that is quite annoying for the user or even on anyone.

NEW UPDATE:

```
function displayNewSnapshot() {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        let latestTimepost = new Date().getTime();
        let imageDataURL = "/images/plate_car.jpg?t=" + latestTimepost;
        $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', imageDataURL);
        console.log(latestTimepost);
    }, 1000);   
}
```

above did work but only once, when simultaneously changing the image, it does not change faster. It could only change faster when i go to other tabs and go back to it without refresh. I did check if the datetime i always include is being updated every second and it does but the image is not. Why is that?

Comment: `let imageDataURL = "http://pilotsitetest2019.hostingerapp.com/proj/openalprx/images/plate_car.jpg?t=" + new Date().getTime();` so it is not cached by browser

Comment: just out of interest why do you expect the image to change if the same image is being loaded every time every 1 sec. feel like im missing something.

Comment: @Seabizkit I believe they intend for the image to change on the server. Some webcams have a mode that operates this way.

Comment: @joyBlanks thanks for the reply :D i did not know it there is such way to do it. I tried it and it happened once but after i did always change the image, it did not update faster compare to before, it could sometimes change when i do go other tabs to check something then going back to its tab, it updates, why is that? i tried printing out the datetime instead 'img loaded' and it does update always but not the image.

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah, my friend and I wanted it that way